# Stop Blogger Side Gadgets scrolling when you reach the bottom

Tags: html, css, scroll, blogger

so [here](http://games-and-geeks.blogspot.com/) is my blog.  I want to let the widgets on the right side scroll up and down with the page but when you reach the bottom they will stop scrolling so that there will always be something showing on the right side of the page.  I am pretty good with html and css but I have to say that editing someone elses code is a giant pain.  If anyone can help me figure this out that would be great.

Comment: Show what you're tried. You can do that with some JavaScript.